# What is the most suitable hibernate.dialect for postgresql 10.5?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, postgresql-10

I am looking at hibernate documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html to try to find which `hibernate.dialect` to use inside persistence.xml

It does not mention a class for Postgres 10.x. Should I use `PostgreSQL94Dialect`?

Comment: And what do you think of this class that is allegedly for `An SQL dialect for Postgres 9.4 and later.` ... do you think that covers Postgres 10.x? Is 10.x later than 9.4? Clearly other JPA providers just autodetect the database and dont rely on users to have to set such things ...

Comment: Hibernate 5.4 has [PostgreSQL10Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL10Dialect.html)

Answer (score 20):

Looking [at newest documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) and it's `PostgreSQL95Dialect`